# Autofac Is it possible to resolve from custom Authorize Filter Attribute, before to be used in ApiController?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, httprequest, autofac

I read the post about autofac in [Authorization Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301227/injecting-dependencies-into-custom-web-api-action-filter-attribute-with-autofac/23356599). And with the understanding of [delegate factory in my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422124/how-to-use-autofac-in-web-api-to-resolve-a-service-at-runtime), here I would like to ask, if it is possible to resolve a dependency from the custom Authorization Attribute.

Here's my code:

1. **`CustomAuthorizationFilterAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute`**

   ```
   protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
       {
           try
           {
               var token = actionContext.Request.GetHeader("Authorization");
               MyUserAccess userAccess = myAccessHelper.GetUserAccess(token);

               //Note that I am adding another property to Request in order to allow the controller to access it
               actionContext.Request.Properties.Add(REQUEST_KEY_USERACCESS, userAccess); 

               return true;
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
               return false;
           }
       }
   ```

Note that, I would like to do the token processing in the `AuthorizeAttribute`. The thing is, that processing doesn't return a `boolean`, but an object of `MyUserAcesss` which is **to be used in the subsequent query**.

2. **`MyController : ApiController`**

   ```
   private ServiceData.Factory myServiceFactory;
   public MyController(ServiceData.Factory myServiceFactory)
   {
       this.myServiceFactory = myServiceFactory;
   }

   public IHttpActionResult GetData([FromUri] MyFilter filter)
   {
       Object myUserAccess;
       bool hasObject = Request.Properties.TryGetValue(REQUEST_KEY_USERACCESS, myUserAccess);
       if (!hasObject)
           return Content(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "No User Access");

       var myService = myServiceFactory.Invoke((MyUserAccess)myUserAccess);
       return Ok(myService.GetSomething());
   }
   ```

Note that in the Web API, i have to perform "`TryGetValue`", and to resolve the service on the spot (after casting the data type). The logic works. BUT, I am curious, can I take that part out? (as it looks repetitive) Ideally, I would like to achieve something as below:

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetData([FromUri] MyFilter filter)
    {
        return Ok(myService.GetSomething());
    }
```

That is to say, as soon as it is landed on the ApiController function, the service has been defined. All I need is to just use it. Wondering if Autofac is able to do this?

**P.S.:**

To generalize the question: 
"Is it possible to Real-Time Resolve a dependency (of an Object X) from Class A which can be subsequently used in Class B? (so in Class B, there is no need to call Invoke)

**P.S.2:**

I learn that apart from adding to the properties, we are able to 'pass that param to the controller' through ControllerContext [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026394/global-variable-in-web-api).

Comment: [Have you read the docs?](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, i scanned through but have no clue. At one point i was thinking whether i should perform the autofac registration at the AuthorizeAttribute. Anyway, do you mean this is actually possible? if yes, i would re-explore those doc...

Comment: Read the part in the docs about filters. Authorize attribute is a filter. The docs are long, but it's worth actually reading them instead of just scanning through.

Comment: Ok Sure. At the moment I could barely swallow and digest the docs LOL. Probably I need to have more trials and errors..

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.getdependencyscope(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Yes Sir. Sorry. My bad. The search keyword for it is "HttpRequestMessage" instead of Autofac. (so i removed that >.<)

Comment: Correct me if am wrong. I tried `Property Injection` and `GetDependencyScope`. But they are not the wanted... Actually to generalize the question, is it possible to Real-Time Resolve a dependency (of an Object X) from Class A which can be subsequently used in Class B? (so in Class B, there is no need to call `Invoke`)